# ArcGIS JS API 3.x - Update the default selected feature highlight styling when a pop up displayed

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online-basemaps

I'm displaying a pop up when a feature is selected on feature layer. I'm also highlighting the polygon boundary with a red line but when the pop up appears the highlighter changes to aqua color which i'm assuming is the default behavior. The highlighter goes back to red as soon as the pop up is closed .

[image]

Without PopUp

[image]

Is there a way to override the default feature highlighter behavior when the Pop Up is displayed or just not show that graphic at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When defining the popup, you can turn off the highlight by setting the [highlight](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/popup-amd.html#highlight) property to false or you can set a specific [marker symbol](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/popup-amd.html#markersymbol), [line symbol](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/popup-amd.html#linesymbol), or [fill symbol](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/popup-amd.html#fillsymbol)

Answer (score 1):

This ESRI example, [Identify with Popup](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/samples/find_popup/), demonstrates setting a custom highlight color.  The relevant code is shown below. When the Popup is created, the `fillSymbol` option overrides the default aqua color with a  `SimpleFillSymbol` object. The first color argument seen here is the outline color (red), and the second color argument is the 'fill' color or the shaded color over the polygon (yellow).

```
var popup = new Popup({
fillSymbol: new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
        new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
        new Color([255, 0, 0]), 2), new Color([255, 255, 0, 0.25]))
    }, domConstruct.create("div"));
```